# Android Layouts and Large Images

Tags: android, layout, android-image

I need to dynamically decode images for my layouts with BitmapFactory.decodeResource due to memory constraints and large file sizes of the images.  I would like to define my layouts graphically using the XML layout editor, but when calling setContentView() or inflating a layout with LayoutInflater in an Activity, the images referenced in the android:src property of image elements will be loaded and cause an OutOfMemoryException.  One way to get around this is to not define the android:src property in the XML image elements and attach the dynamically decoded images to an inflated layout programmatically with ImageView.setImageBitmap after they are decoded.  However, not defining android:src means I lose the ability to graphically define my layouts.  Another approach would be to use small placeholder images when graphically designing the layout and replacing them at runtime with the decoded image.  That's a pain because I'd need to keep a separate copy of all image files for this purpose.

Can anyone suggest an approach to follow that would allow me to dynamically decode / attach image files to layout elements progammatically without losing the ability to graphically design my layouts?  I really don't want to manually construct the entire layout with code or maintain separate 'design copies' of images.

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Answer (score 0):

Please see:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

they got tons of tips and sample codes that you may use. Aside from that, you may also use Bitmap's .compress() method to have a compressed version of the bitmap

Comment: I've gone through these recommendations including decoding bitmaps at smaller sample rates, implementing a LruCache, and recycling bitmaps when I'm done with them.  The basic issue I have is that I have to load my resized bitmaps dynamically, but doing that restricts me from using XML layouts unless I use placeholder images.  I want to inflate layouts with the resized images.  But there doesn't seem to be a way to set the source value for image elements prior to inflating the view.